# Exit code as variable? $? is always zero

Tags: bash

I noticed something strange (at least for me it's strange). I am writing a script and I need 0 or 1 as exit codes. So far so good. I have them in a simple if-else with echo $? above each condition but when I make the echo $? as a variable to call it's always showing 0 as exit code.

```
#!/bin/bash

exit=`echo $?`

DIRECTORY="/some/dir"

if [[ $(stat -c "%a" "$DIRECTORY") == "777" ]]
then
        echo $?
        #echo "The exit code is: $exit"
else
        echo $?
        #echo "The exit code is: $exit"
fi

#EOF
```

If use just "echo $?" it's all good. I receive 0 or 1. But in the commented part I always receive 0.

Comment: When is exit=\`echo $?\` evaluated?

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding the question? How come evaluated and which one - the one above the conditional or these inside?

Comment: `exit=$?` works just as well as `exit=$(echo $?)`.

Comment: It occurs to me that this is rather unclear. Do you want the status of the `stat` command or of the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the value of `exit` at the top of the code.  This remains unchanged throughout the script.  This is why you always get the same value.

Instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir='/some/dir'

if [[ "$(stat -c "%a" "$dir")" == "777" ]]; then
    status=0
    printf 'Permissions are 777 (status=%d)\n' "$status"
else
    status=1
    printf 'Permissions are not 777 (status=%d)\n' "$status"
fi
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh

dir='/some/dir'

case "$(stat -c "%a" "$dir")" in
    777) echo 'Permissions are 777';     status=0 ;;
    *)   echo 'Permissions are not 777'; status=1 ;;
esac
```

Note that there is actually no need to investigate `$?` here.  If the test succeeds, you know that it's going to be 0, otherwise non-zero.

Answer (score 4):

The `$?` construct contains the status code of the last command executed - *exactly* the last command.

The `[[` is a command (bash test). Hence, you are testing the result of test.

To fix it, save the result first. For example:

```
result=$(stat -c "%a" "$DIRECTORY")
status=$?
... do stuff with status and result
```

Comment: I assumed that was what the OP wanted.